# Changing a differential expression into form $f ' (x, y, z)$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I need to evaluate line integral of
$$(2xy-z) dx + (yz) dy + (x) dz$$
over any path from $(1,0,0)$ to $(2,1,4)$.

I thought of integrating once from $(1,0,0)$ to $(2,0,0)$ then to $(2,1,0)$ and lastly to $(2,1,4)$.

...but that wouldn't necessarily be valid for *any* path.
I think I need to convert the expression in the form $d(f(x, y, z))$
but I'm being unable to do so.

Comment: That is not a conservative field.  Are you sure the problem is asking for a path-independent solution, or could it be asking you to integrate over any path you so choose?

Comment: @anorton yes.
_F = (2xy−z)i+(yz)j+(x)k_
Evaluate _∫F.dr_ along any path from _(1,0,0)_ to _(2,1,4)_

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be the path of integration, $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(2xy−z,yz,x)$ the vector field, and $d\mathbf{r}=(dx,dy,dz)$ an infinitesimal displacement along $C$.

Choose $C$ to be the line segment from $(1,0,0)$ to $(2,1,4)$. A parametrization for the line is given by $\mathbf{r}(t)=(1,0,0)+t(1,1,4)=(t+1,t,4t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Note that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))=(2t^2-2t,4t^2,t+1)$ and $\mathbf{r}'(t)=(1,1,4)$. Now we can evaluate the line integral:

$$\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \int_{t=0}^{1} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \,dt = \int_{t=0}^{1} 6t^2+2t+4 \,dt = \left[2t^3+t^2+4t\right]_{t=0}^{1} = 7$$

However, it is to be noted that $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{F}=(-y,-2,-2x)\ne\mathbf{0}$, so the integral depends on $C$.